# Run VSCode remote-ssh from within WSL to another Remote GCP instance

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I have a windows 10 desktop which is heavily protected by the Admin and have Ubuntu 20 WSL installed in my windows 10.

**Objective**
I want to run VScode remote-ssh from within WSL to my GCP instance which is a high configuration machine for code development and execution.

**Problem**
I am getting an error while performing remote-ssh to the GCP instance from within WSL vscode that says connection timeout.

**Steps Taken**

1. Open WSL
2. Generate id_rsa.pub using ssh-keygen
3. Open Vscode > remote-ssh
4. Add ssh user@IP of the instance
5. Connect to the Host from VScode

**What I am able to do**

1. I am able to do ssh into the GCP instance through my WSL.
2. I am able to open VScode in my WSL